# Nested bash command quote issues

Tags: linux, bash

I have an app that sends commands to bash like so:

```
/bin/bash -c "<command goes here>"
```

This works great but I have hit a problem with a slightly more complicated command.  This command grabs a tar from an SSH server, shows a progress bar with `pv` and then saves it to a local user's directory.

```
su -c "ssh -p 1234 remoteuser@123.123.123.123 'cd /home/ && tar -cf - remoteuser/' | pv > /home/staging/localuser/staging.tar" localuser
```

Running this command on the command line manually works great but I can't for the life of me work out how to pass this as an argument to `/bin/bash/`.

I have tried:

```
/bin/bash -c "su -c "ssh -p 1234 remoteuser@123.123.123.123 'cd /home/ && tar -cf - remoteuser/' | pv > /home/staging/localuser/staging.tar" localuser"
```

And various combinations using different syntax but I am just guessing as I don't really understand why it's not working.

I have broken it down to a simpler example and realised it works if inner command uses single quote like this simple example that gets the home path:

```
bash -c "su -c 'cd ~ && pwd' localuser"
```

but trying that on larger command causes it to fail:

```
/bin/bash -c "su -c 'ssh -p 1234 remoteuser@123.123.123.123 'cd /home/ && tar -cf - remoteuser/' | pv > /home/staging/localuser/staging.tar' localuser"
```

It says `no passwd entry for user /home` so the command is getting broken up I guess buy the nested single quotes but im not sure how to fix this.

I tried putting double quotes outside the single quotes:

```
/bin/bash -c "su -c 'ssh -p 1234 remoteuser@123.123.123.123 "'cd /home/ && tar -cf - remoteuser/'" | pv > /home/staging/localuser/staging.tar' localuser"
```

But then it says it can't find the directory.  It looks like I just need to tweak the command a bit but I can't figure it out, can anyone help?

Comment: Normally when a program "sends a command to bash", it means that the program invokes `execl("/bin/bash", "-c", yourcommand, NULL);`. This means that your string should not be escaped. You should most definitely not be trying to write a `bash -c something` command, because that implies going through another shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a matter of quoting in the right way. There is more than one way to do this. I find double quotes easier to work with for this case:

```
echo "su -c \"ssh -p 1234 remoteuser@123.123.123.123 'cd /home/ && tar -cf - remoteuser/' | pv > /home/staging/localuser/staging.tar\" localuser"
```

Prints:

```
su -c "ssh -p 1234 remoteuser@123.123.123.123 'cd /home/ && tar -cf - remoteuser/' | pv > /home/staging/localuser/staging.tar" localuser
```

Which I think is what you are looking for. That is, escaping with `\"` any double quotes inside the outer double quotes. So try:

```
/bin/bash -c "su -c \"ssh -p 1234 remoteuser@123.123.123.123 'cd /home/ && tar -cf - remoteuser/' | pv > /home/staging/localuser/staging.tar\" localuser"
```

Comment: Great man I can't thank you enough.  I have been messing round 2 hours trying to figure that out.  It's working great now

Answer (score 3):

This is where here-documents come in handy:

```
bash <<'END'
su -c "ssh -p 1234 remoteuser@123.123.123.123 'cd /home/ && tar -cf - remoteuser/' | pv > /home/staging/localuser/staging.tar" localuser
END
```

Note the `-c` option has been removed: bash will read the commands from stdin.